# How to connect to redshift using groovy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, groovy, amazon-redshift, apache-nifi

I am trying to establish a connection to Redshift using groovy and execute a query, I am not able to find any resources on how to do this. Please provide a solution.

I was trying to this in JAVA but couldn't find a similar solution in groovy

Comment: if you have code for java - it should work for groovy

Answer (score 1):

if you have code for java - it should work for groovy maybe with minor changes.

here is how jdbc connection in groovy could look like:

```js
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='com.amazon.redshift', module='redshift-jdbc42', version='2.1.0.9')

import groovy.sql.Sql

def props = [
    url:      'jdbc:redshift://adee-cluster.c9ld7lgff4o4.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5555/dev', 
    user:     'awsuser', 
    password: 'changeme', 
    driver:   'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver'
]

Sql.withInstance(props){sql->
    println 'connected'
    def query = "select id, first_name, last_name from public.employee where first_name like :firstName"
    def params = [firstName:'Rob%']
    sql.eachRow(query, params){row->
        println "row: id=${row.id}, name=${row.first_name} ${row.last_name}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out ExecuteGroovyScript as well, it offers a SQL object that can make use of certain properties like a DBCPConnectionPool you can configure for Redshift